# Convert .png into "lossy" .pdf

Tags: pdf, png, jpeg, imagemagick-convert

I would like to convert a `.png` into a `.pdf` (I guess it's actually being embedded) whilst reducing the filesize. So I thought, jpeg-compression might be a good choice. So far it works well with ImageMagick using 2 commands: Converting it into a `.jpg` first and then converting it into a `.pdf`.

```
convert image.png -quality 92 image.jpg
convert image.jpg image.pdf
```

Now, is there a way to do that in only one command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageMagick, try

```
convert image.png -compress JPEG -quality 92 image.pdf
```